# Php object oriented scope accessing to a array

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm looking to get my head around this theory on how to access a variable or an array in php oop.

What i mean is: I'm creating a wordpress plugin(which i know doesn't matter for this question).
- let's say I have backend class in it I have a method that creates a array of text fields and thoses texts fields are asign to specific users. 
- then in another file I have a frontend class that display's the array created in the back end.

How can I access, the array created in the backend, in the frontend class?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You would store the data in a database usually or JSON file and parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You would store the data in a database usually or JSON file and parse the JSON.

If you are talking about a wordpress plugin you would use a database table, word press has a tutorial for setting up  database table for your plugin.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins